# Vbscript to find critical process

Tags: vbscript

I wrote a vbscript to find the critical process details from server.I have few process name if that process exists then the script should give the mentioned output.But the problem here is even though if the process exist or not exist the script give same output as **"CriticalProcesses=NA"**. Can anyone help to fix this ? Any help is much appreciated

```
   strComputer = "."
   Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
   Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process", "WQL", _
                                          wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)

   For Each objItem In colItems
   'WScript.Echo "Caption: " & objItem.Caption

      Dim process

      Process = objItem.Caption

   Next

   If inStr(process, "SQLserver") Or inStr(process, "mysql") then

      wscript.echo "CriticalProcesses=Database"

   else if inStr(process, "java") Or inStr(process, "weblogic") Then

      wscript.echo "CriticalProcesses=wls"

   else

      wscript.echo "CriticalProcesses=NA"

   End if        
End if
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are iterating through your processes in a for loop and then you test the process name outside of the loop. So your `If instr(process..` bit only checks the **last** process found from your `for` loop.

To fix, stick the `if` test inside your loop, so it can test each process it finds.

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process", "WQL", _
    wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)

For Each objItem In colItems
    'WScript.Echo "Caption: " & objItem.Caption
    Dim process
    Process = objItem.Caption

    If inStr(process, "SQLserver") Or inStr(process, "mysql") Then
        wscript.echo "CriticalProcesses=Database"
    ElseIF inStr(process, "java") Or inStr(process, "weblogic") Then
        wscript.echo "CriticalProcesses=wls"
    Else
        'wscript.echo "CriticalProcesses=NA"
    End If
Next
```

I've also changed your `Else If` to an `ElseIf` and removed the unnecessary second `End If`.

Lastly, I commented out that echo in your `Else` since you probably don't want the script to `Echo` `NA` over and over and over again. At least... I wasn't to hip on pressing Enter 200 times.

---

To capture whether a `wls` or `database` type process is running and then only echo once at the end, you can capture the true/false for each type in a boolean variable, then test *after* the `for` loop:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process", "WQL", _
    wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)

Dim hasDBProcess
Dim hasWLSProcess

hasDBProcess = False
hasWLSProcess = False

For Each objItem In colItems
    'WScript.Echo "Caption: " & objItem.Caption
    Dim process
    Process = objItem.Caption

    If inStr(process, "SQLserver") Or inStr(process, "mysql") Then
        hasDBProcess = True
    ElseIF inStr(process, "java") Or inStr(process, "weblogic") Then
        hasWLSProcess = True
    End If
Next

If hasDBProcess Then 
    wscript.echo "CriticalProcess=Database"
ElseIf hasWLSProcess Then
    wscript.echo "CriticalProcess=wls"
Else
    wscript.echo "CriticalProcess=NA"
End if
```

Comment: Thanks much.Now the script start working.but as the if condition is inside the loop if multiple java.exe presents it gives multiple results and also i even require to print NA if no mentioned process available

Comment: So instead of echoing in the for loop, maybe just use a boolean to capture whether you found a wls or database type process, then outside the loop test the boolean and echo. I will give an example in my answer.

Comment: For Each objItem In colItems
      Dim process :   Process = objItem.Caption
     If inStr(process, "SQLserver") Or inStr(process, "mysql") then
         Processes=Database
      ElseIf inStr(process, "java") Or inStr(process, "weblogic") Then
         Processes=wls
 else
        Processes=NA
            End if   
   Next
If Processes=Database Then
wscript.echo "tr_CriticalProcesses=Database"
ElseIf Processes=wls Then
wscript.echo "tr_CriticalProcesses=wls"
else
wscript.echo "tr_CriticalProcesses=NA"
End If

Comment: That won't work because you are iterating through every process. This, again, will only tell you what the LAST process was in your `For` loop. You'll need to set seperate variables to track the process types that you are interested in, then test those variables after the for loop to find what you want. See the updated answer for the way to do that. If you want to get fancy and only have one variable, you could use an array or a collection object. But for starters, I would just stick with the booleans.

Comment: I just noticed a mistake in that second bit of code I wrote where I had `hasWLSProcess = True` above the `for` loop. I just changed that to `hasWLSProcess = False`. Essentially we want those boolean variables to be false before the for loop. Then if anything is found, we set them to true inside the loop.